# The properties "target" and "length" doesn't seem to exist on type "{}" in angular 2?

Tags: node.js, angular

The properties "target" and "length" doesn't seem to exist on type "{}" in angular 2?

Here's the code:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCylr.png]

Answer (score 5):

There are two way to do that.

1) Without strong typing

```
var keyups = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup')
  .map((e: any) => e.target.value) // or (<any>e).target.value
  .debounceTime(200)
  .filter(text => text && text.length >= 3)

  keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

2) With strong typing

```
var keyups = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup')
  .map((e: KeyboardEvent) => (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value)
  .debounceTime(200)
  .filter(text => text && text.length >= 3)

  keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

And i think that importing the entirely rxjs library is redundantly, so it might be like:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
```

***One Note***: rxjs/**O**bservable at the first line

See also live **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KijpcipR1TKO94MSaHEL?p=preview)**